# Why is substitution allowed in Taylor Series?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

While finding the Taylor Series of a function, **when** are you allowed to substitute? And **why**?

For example:

Around $x=0$ for $e^{2x}$ I apparently am allowed to substitute $u=2x$ and then use the known series for $e^u$. But for $e^{x+1}$ I am not allowed to substitute $u=x+1$.

I know the technique for finding the Taylor Series of $e^{x+1}$ around $x=0$ by taking $e^{x+1}=e\times e^x$. However, I am looking for understanding and intuition for when and why it is allowed to apply substitution.

Note: there are several question that are similar to this one, but I have found none that actually answers the question "why"; or that shows a complete proof.

---

EDIT: Thanks to the answer of Markus Scheuer I should refine the question to cases where the series is finite, for example $n\to3$

Comment: The real questioni is: why on Earth shall you substitute $u = 2x$?? Leave $e^{2x}$ and use the Taylor series for that!

Comment: @AlanTuring The point is that I try to understand why I can do that for $e^{2x}$ but not for $e^{x+1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A function $f(x)$ analytic at $x=0$ can be represented as power series within an open disc with radius of convergence $R$.
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\qquad\qquad \qquad |x|<R
> \end{align*}
>
> *Any* substitution $x=g(u)$ is admissible as long as we respect the *radius of convergence*.
>   \begin{align*}
> f(g(u))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(g(u)\right)^n\qquad\qquad\quad |g(u)|<R
> \end{align*}

We know $f(u)=e^u$ can be represented as Taylor series convergent for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the radius of convergence $R=\infty$.
\begin{align*}
f(u)=e^u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad u\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

> **Substitution $u=2x$**
>
> We consider
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(2x)=e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad 2x\in \mathbb{R}
> \end{align*}
>
> This substitution is admissible for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ since $$2x\in\mathbb{R}\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}$$ So, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(2x)=e^{2x}$ is $\infty$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
f(2x)=e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

> **Substitution $u=x+1$**
>
> We consider
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(x+1)=e^{x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad x+1\in \mathbb{R}
> \end{align*}
>
> This substitution is admissible for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ since $$x+1\in\mathbb{R}\qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}$$ So, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(x+1)=e^{x+1}$ is $\infty$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
f(x+1)=e^{x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}\qquad\qquad\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

> We also obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> e\cdot e^x&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{l=0}^n\frac{1}{(n-l)!}\cdot\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{l=0}^n\binom{n}{l}x^l\right)\frac{1}{n!}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}\\
> &=e^{x+1}
> \end{align*}

**Conclusion:** We can use any substitution for convenience as long as we respect the radius of convergence.

Comment: I understand now that one is allowed to substitute in this case if $n\to\infty$. Is it correct to say that the series of $e^{x+1}$ that is the result of substitution is centered around $x=-1$, while the series that is calulated directly is centered around $x=0$? And doesn't this make a difference if I want to give an approximation of $e^{x+1}$ around $x=0$? I mean if I want to approximate I usually don't let $n\to\infty$, but rather to a fixed number, say $n\to3$. Would that make the case different?

Comment: @ImreVégh: Yes, it is correct that the representation of $e^{x+1}$ above is centered around $x=-1$. Note, that *if* we have a power series centered around some value $x=x_0$, we can select *any* value $x_1$ within the disc of convergence $x_1\in d(x_0,R)$ of $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$ as new center by expanding $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n ((x-x_1)-(x_0-x_1))^n$ at powers of $x-x_1$. The new radius of convergence $R_1$ is *at least* as big, that $d(x_1,R_1)\subset d(x_0,R)$.

Comment: @ImreVégh: If we want to expand the special case $e^{x+1}$ around $x=0$ we can go the easy way (as you already did) and write $e^{x+1}=e\cdot e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e}{n!} x^n$ with coefficients $\frac{e}{n!}$ of $x^n$. The somewhat more cumbersome  way would be to expand $(x+1)^n$ in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{n!}$ and arrange the terms according to increasing powers of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If $ f(x)=P_n(x)+x^n\epsilon(x)$ then

$f(u(x))=P(u(x))+(u(x))^n\epsilon(u(x))$

with $\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$.

thus we need that

$\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(u(x))=0$

so, we must have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}u(x)=0$$

Comment: Hmm, I understand. And why is substitution allowed in the first place? When $\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(u(x))=0$?

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $2x$ is a product and as $x\to 0$ it remains a small number.

The quantity $x+n$ for $n\neq 0$ is not a little quantity anymore, and so you are not anymore around zero but you're around $n$.